# How to swap two characters in SQL* Plus , using REPLACE()

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, swap

I'm trying to swap 'a' with 'i' and 'i' with 'a' , using REPLACE function.

**Example :**

**Before swap -> Muradin

After  swap  -> Muridan**

However I fail to do so.

I've tried the following :

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(name,'a','i'),'i','a')
FROM mytable;
```

It doesn't work , naturally. Because the first replace will be commited and 'a' will not exist anymore.

I did not find any similar solution to this ,any idea how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TRANSLATE` function:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('Muradin', 'ai', 'ia') AS result
FROM dual;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/9265/0)**</kbd>

or multiple `REPLACE` (warning character cannot be in string like `^`):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('Muradin','i','^'),'a','i'),'^','a') AS result
FROM dual;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/9267/0)**</kbd>